# Modify Observable if values exist in another Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to compare 2 observables and modify the source observable if a value exists in the second observable.

example:

```
[

    {
      value: 3
    }
]


[
    {
      value: 1
      exists: false
    },
    {
      value: 2
      exists: false
    },
    {
      value: 3
      exists: true
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

something like will work?

```
let obs2$ = Rx.Observable.of(2,4,6,8);

let obs1$ = Rx.Observable.of(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7)
         .switchMap(x=> obs2$
                        .first(v => v===x, v=>true, false)
                        .map(exist => ({exist:exist, value:x})))
        .subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```

Comment: This is headed in the right direction I feel, how can I return an array that looks like this [{1, false}, {2, true},{3, false}, {5, false}, {6, true}, {7, false}, {8, false}]

Comment: based on the numbers you provided.

Comment: {1, false} is incorrect javascript object. javascript has key:value format where key is a string. you can't return it like that.

Comment: I meant like this [{
      value: 2
      exists: false
    },
    {
      value: 3
      exists: true
    }]

Comment: there is also a distinct operator https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/distinct.md

Comment: the source will only ever had one of each, I want to know which of those exist in the comparer.